# Terminal and Python relationship

Tags: command-line, python

How is the Terminal in Ubuntu and Python programming connected?

Can we use Python to control the system in Terminal?

I am a complete newbie,so please guide, I installed Ubuntu out of sheer enthusiasm of learning more about the flexibility and proper usage of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal in Ubuntu (like most other Linux distributions) uses [bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) which can be used to perform tasks and functions programmatically. Python also comes with most Linux distributions but it is not "burned" into Linux like bash is.

You can use python to interact with your computer by using [libraries such as os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) but for most tasks you may be better off using bash.

Of course learning both will help you in the long run. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use the `python` or `python3` interpreter from the command line, from the python documentation:

> When invoking Python, you may specify any of these options:
>
> ```
> python3 [-bBdEhiIOqsSuvVWx?] [-c command | -m module-name | script | - ] [args]
> ```
>
> The most common use case is, of course, a simple invocation of a
>   script:
>
> ```
> python3 myscript.py
> ```

A quick example:

```
$ python3 -c "print('Hello world')"
Hello world
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html